# SQLiteException table depot has no column named ... , while compiling INSERT INTO

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get following error message in my little android application:

> SQLiteException: table depot has no column named price_per_unit: , while compiling INSERT INTO depot(...)

But hell, how can this happen? I am using a Metadata-class for providing all names:

My create table is this one:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DepotTableMetaData.TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                + DepotTableMetaData._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_QRCODE + " INTEGER,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_AMOUNT + " DOUBLE,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_UNIT + " TEXT,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU + " DOUBLE,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_TOTAL + " DOUBLE,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_COMMENT + " TEXT,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE + " INTEGER,"
                + DepotTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE + " INTEGER"
                + ");");
```

while my `DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU` exactly means the `price_per_unit` and I never call again this `price_per_unit`, I only refer to it as `DepotTableMetaData_ITEM_PPU`. What can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable 'DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU' is probably set to 'price_per_unit'.

Comment: yes, and it's intended to be that, because it's the name of the column... i later insert some data to it via
content.put(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU, Double.parseDouble("22"));
i don't really understand where's the problem >.<

Comment: After you create the table do a 'describe' or 'show create' (or whatever the sqlite variant is) and see what columns have actually been created.

Comment: I only get some temp-databses which i can't access for some reason

Comment: ah, i know managed to access the table... let me try something.. (dumping the old one, making a new one)

Comment: narf seemed to Work.. however i now got some other errors... which are way more confusing^^ but thanks however.